# I want to present bank transactions for passbook from given data?

Tags: sql, oracle

| TR_DATE | ACC_NAME | TYPE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2017 | AVNEESH | CR | 60000 |
| 02-01-2017 | AVNEESH | DB | 8000 |
| 03-01-2017 | AVNEESH | CR | 8000 |
| 04-01-2017 | AVNEESH | DB | 5000 |
| 01-01-2017 | NUPUR | CR | 10000 |
| 02-01-2017 | NUPUR | DB | 8000 |
| 03-01-2017 | NUPUR | CR | 8000 |

And expected result for above data is

| TR_DATE | ACC_NAME | TYPE | AMOUNT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2017 | AVNEESH | CR | 60000 | 60000 |
| 02-01-2017 | AVNEESH | DB | 8000 | 52000 |
| 03-01-2017 | AVNEESH | CR | 8000 | 60000 |
| 04-01-2017 | AVNEESH | DB | 5000 | 55000 |
| 01-01-2017 | NUPUR | CR | 10000 | 10000 |
| 02-01-2017 | NUPUR | DB | 8000 | 2000 |
| 03-01-2017 | NUPUR | CR | 8000 | 10000 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the analytic version of the `sum()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUM.html#GUID-5610BE2C-CFE5-446F-A1F7-B924B5663220), with a case expression to turn debits into negative amounts, and a window clause to apply the sum to amounts up to the current row's date:

```
select tr_date, acc_name, type, amount,
  sum(case when type = 'DB' then -1 else 1 end * amount)
    over (partition by acc_name order by tr_date) as balance
from passbook
order by acc_name, tr_date
```

| TR_DATE | ACC_NAME | TYPE | AMOUNT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 | AVNEESH | CR | 60000 | 60000 |
| 2017-01-02 | AVNEESH | DB | 8000 | 52000 |
| 2017-01-03 | AVNEESH | CR | 8000 | 60000 |
| 2017-01-04 | AVNEESH | DB | 5000 | 55000 |
| 2017-01-01 | NUPUR | CR | 10000 | 10000 |
| 2017-01-02 | NUPUR | DB | 8000 | 2000 |
| 2017-01-03 | NUPUR | CR | 8000 | 10000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ejpZBbJO)